# Expo Facebook Login- Producing Invalid Tokens

Tags: facebook, react-native, redux, expo

I followed the docs to use the Facebook Login SDK. Everything works except for the fact that the token that is generated does not work for our API. Our API takes the user-generated token as a header so that it can make requests. I know the reason why it isn't working is that I am logging in with Facebook, but there is no account created on our API. Facebook will not give me access to a user's password (for obvious reasons), so I can't generate an account from the information provided from Facebook.

I think the answer lies with App Access Tokens. If someone could help me out I would really appreciate it!

code:

```
export const logInFB = () => async dispatch => {
  const { type, token } = await Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync('**Blocking this out**', {
      permissions: ['public_profile'],
    });
  console.log('token');
  console.log(token);
  if (type === 'success') {
    // Get the user's name using Facebook's Graph API
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}`);
    console.log('fb token')
    console.log(response);
    dispatch(fbLoginToken(token));
    Alert.alert(
      'Logged in!',
      `Hi ${(await response.json()).name}!`,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token} of course require a user access token.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the `fields` property in the URL. ex: `&fields=id,name,email,about,picture`

Please refer to this example: https://snack.expo.io/@bacon/facebook

```
const response = await fetch(
      `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=${token}&fields=id,name,email,about,picture`
    );
const responseJSON = JSON.stringify(await response.json());
this.setState({ responseJSON });
```